# Why do modules sometimes raise an UnboundLocalError when imported locally?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, scope

I was stumped by a situation where the python interpreter complained about a local variable `foo` being referenced before assignment, even though I had clearly imported the `foo` package and never re-assigned it.

Consider the following code:

```
import foo.bar
def qux():
    if(foo.bar.fred()):
        import foo.baz
        print(foo.baz.waldo())
qux()
```

This raises an UnboundLocalError at the line with `if(foo.bar.fred()):`.

This problem seems to have specific considerations that differ from most UnboundLocalError situations, and I couldn't find this specific situation posted on stack overflow or any other site.

Why does the above code raise an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this exception is raised because of an implicit (hidden) re-assignment.  When `foo.baz` is imported within the local scope of the function, it re-assigns `foo` to be a local variable, as opposed to a global one.